# malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted) Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada) - C - gcc - Linux

Tags: c, linux, alocação, gcc, malloc

Olá, estou iniciando em programação e estou tendo um erro que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum. Usei um do while para repetir o programa. O problema é que eu estou usando a alocação dinamica de memória com o malloc() e preciso usar o free() para desalocar, porém não sei se fiz certo. O programa roda normal no mac e no windows, porém no linux é exibido a seguinte mensagem na hora que o programa vai reexecutar a função malloc():

```
malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Deixei a função da alocação de memória no arquivo "vetor.c"  e a de liberar a memória no próprio main, pois estava testando.

vou postar todos os arquivos aqui.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "main.h"

void liberaMem(VETOR* v){
    // Não está funcionando corretamente
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(v->vetor)/sizeof(v->vetor[0]); i++){
        free(v->vetor[i]);
    }
    
}

int main() {
    // Acentuação
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int acabou = 0;

    abertura();

    do{
        VETOR v;
        int escolha, escolhaCompararVal;

        inicializaVetor(&escolha, &v);
        organizaVetor(&escolha, &v);
        comparaVetores(&escolhaCompararVal, &escolha, &v);

        printf("\nVocê deseja usar outro vetor?\n1) Sim\n2) Não\n\nEscolha: ");
        scanf(" %d", &acabou);
        acabou--;

        liberaMem(&v);

    } while (!acabou);

    if(acabou == 1){
        printf("\nTudo bem, até mais! :3\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nValor invalido!\n\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

vetor.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "main.h"

void qualTamanhoDoVetor(int *tamanhoDoVetor) {
    printf("\nInsira a quantidade de números dentro do vetor:\n");
    scanf("%d", tamanhoDoVetor);
}

void geraAleatorio(int tamanhoDoVetor, int vetor[]) {
    int limiteCasasAleatorios = 100; // 100 = de 0 a 99.
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoDoVetor; i++) {
        vetor[i] = rand() % limiteCasasAleatorios; 
    }
}

void leDados(int tamanhoDoVetor, int vetor[]) {
    printf("\nInsira os valores dentro do vetor:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoDoVetor; i++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
}

void printVetor(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor){
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoDoVetor; i++){
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void printMerge(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= tamanhoDoVetor; i++) {
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void executaBubbleSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor) {
    clock_t inicioCronometro = clock();
    bubbleSort(vetor, tamanhoDoVetor - 1);
    clock_t fimCronometro = clock();
    contagemCronometro(0, inicioCronometro, fimCronometro);
}

void executaInsertionSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor) {
    clock_t inicioCronometro = clock();
    insertionSort(vetor, tamanhoDoVetor);
    clock_t fimCronometro = clock();
    contagemCronometro(1, inicioCronometro, fimCronometro);
}

void executaMergeSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor) {
    clock_t inicioCronometro = clock();
    mergeSort(vetor, 0, tamanhoDoVetor);
    clock_t fimCronometro = clock();
    contagemCronometro(2, inicioCronometro, fimCronometro);
}


void inicializaVetor(int* escolha, VETOR* v){

        qualTamanhoDoVetor(&v->tamanhoDoVetor);
        
        // Alocação dinâmica de memória
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(v->vetor)/sizeof(v->vetor[0]); i++){
            v->vetor[i] = (int*) malloc(v->tamanhoDoVetor *sizeof(int));
        }

        printf("\nVocê deseja usar números aleatórios ou escolher os valores a serem ordenados?\n1) Aleatórios\n2) Escolher os valores\n\nDigite: ");
        scanf("%d", escolha);
        
        switch (*escolha){
        case 1:
            geraAleatorio(v->tamanhoDoVetor, v->vetor[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            leDados(v->tamanhoDoVetor, v->vetor[0]);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Erro! Valor inválido!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Copia o vetor desordenado para os outros vetores
        for(int i = 0; i <=  v->tamanhoDoVetor; i++){
            v->vetor[2][i] = v->vetor[1][i] = v->vetor[0][i];
        }
}

void organizaVetor(int* escolha, VETOR* v){
    printf("\nQual algorítmo de ordenação você deseja usar?\n1) Bubble Sort\n2) Insertion Sort\n3) Merge Sort\n\nDigite: ");
        scanf("%d", escolha);

        if(*escolha == 1){
            printf("\n\n-- BUBBLE SORT --\n");
        } else if(*escolha == 2){
            printf("\n\n-- INSERTION SORT --\n");
        } else if(*escolha == 3){
            printf("\n\n-- MERGE SORT --\n");
        } else {
            printf("\nErro! Opção Inválida!\n");
            exit(1);
        };

        printf("\n\033[1;31mVetor antes da ordenação:\n");
        printVetor(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);

        printf("\n\033[0;32mVetor depois da ordenação:\n");

        switch (*escolha) {
        case 1:
            executaBubbleSort(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printVetor(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printTempo(*escolha);
            break;
        case 2:
            executaInsertionSort(v->vetor[1], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printVetor(v->vetor[1], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printTempo(*escolha);
            break;
        case 3:
            executaMergeSort(v->vetor[2], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printMerge(v->vetor[2], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printTempo(*escolha);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
}
void comparaVetores(int* escolhaCompararVal, int* escolha, VETOR* v){
    printf("Você deseja comparar os valores?\n1) Sim\n2) Não\n\nEscolha: ");
        scanf("%d", escolhaCompararVal);
        
        if (*escolhaCompararVal == 1) {
            switch (*escolha) {
            case 1:
                // bubble sort
                executaInsertionSort(v->vetor[1], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
                executaMergeSort(v->vetor[2], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
                printTempos();
                break;
            case 2:
                // insertion sort
                executaBubbleSort(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
                executaMergeSort(v->vetor[2], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
                printTempos();
                break;
            case 3:
                // merge sort
                executaBubbleSort(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
                executaInsertionSort(v->vetor[1], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
                printTempos();
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nErro! Opção Inválida!\n");
                exit(1);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

cronometro.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "main.h"

float algoritmos[3];

void printTempo(int escolha){
    printf("\n\033[0;37mTempo de processamento da ordenação: %.5lfms\n\n", algoritmos[escolha - 1]);
}

void printTempos(){
    printf("\nTempo de processamento da ordenação Bubble Sort: %.5lfms\n", algoritmos[0]);
    printf("Tempo de processamento da ordenação Insertion Sort: %.5lfms\n", algoritmos[1]);
    printf("Tempo de processamento da ordenação Merge Sort: %.5lfms\n", algoritmos[2]);
}

void contagemCronometro(int escolha, unsigned long inicio, unsigned long fim){
    algoritmos[escolha] = (double)(fim - inicio)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);
}
```

abertura.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abertura(){
    printf("\n-- Algoritmos de ordenação --\n");
}
```

BubbleSort.c

```
/*
                    Referência:
    https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#C
*/

void troca(int *a, int *b){ 
    int temp = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = temp; 
}

void bubbleSort(int *vetor, int tamanhoDoVetor){ 
    
    if (tamanhoDoVetor < 1){
        return;
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoDoVetor; i++){
        if (vetor[i] > vetor[i + 1]){
            troca(&vetor[i], &vetor[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    bubbleSort(vetor, tamanhoDoVetor - 1); 
}
```

InsertionSort.c

```
/* 
                    Referência:
    https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#C
*/

void insertionSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor){
    int i, j, valorDovetor;
    for (i = 1; i < tamanhoDoVetor; i++) {
        valorDovetor = vetor[i];
        j = i - 1;
        
        while (j >= 0 && vetor[j] > valorDovetor) { // Enquanto j >= 0 e o numero j do vetor > valorDovetor, faça:
            vetor[j + 1] = vetor[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        vetor[j + 1] = valorDovetor;
    }
}
```

MergeSort.c

```
/*
                    Referência:
    https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#C%C3%B3digo_em_C
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int vetor[], int comeco, int meio, int fim) {
    int com1 = comeco, com2 = meio+1, comAux = 0, tam = fim-comeco+1;
    int *vetAux;
    vetAux = (int*)malloc(tam * sizeof(int));

    while(com1 <= meio && com2 <= fim){
        if(vetor[com1] < vetor[com2]) {
            vetAux[comAux] = vetor[com1];
            com1++;
        } else {
            vetAux[comAux] = vetor[com2];
            com2++;
        }
        comAux++;
    }

    while(com1 <= meio){  //Caso ainda haja elementos na primeira metade
        vetAux[comAux] = vetor[com1];
        comAux++;
        com1++;
    }

    while(com2 <= fim) {   //Caso ainda haja elementos na segunda metade
        vetAux[comAux] = vetor[com2];
        comAux++;
        com2++;
    }

    for(comAux = comeco; comAux <= fim; comAux++){    //Move os elementos de volta para o vetor original
        vetor[comAux] = vetAux[comAux-comeco];
    }
    
    free(vetAux);
}

void mergeSort(int vetor[], int comeco, int fim){
    if (comeco < fim) {
        int meio = (fim+comeco)/2;

        mergeSort(vetor, comeco, meio);
        mergeSort(vetor, meio+1, fim);
        merge(vetor, comeco, meio, fim);
    }
}
```

main.h

```
// Vetor
void abertura();
struct vetor{int *vetor[3], tamanhoDoVetor;};
typedef struct vetor VETOR;
void qualTamanhoDoVetor(int *tamanhoDoVetor);
void geraAleatorio(int tamanhoDoVetor, int vetor[]);
void leDados(int tamanhoDoVetor, int vetor[]);
void printVetor(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void printMerge(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void executaBubbleSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void executaInsertionSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void executaMergeSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void inicializaVetor(int* escolha, VETOR* v);
void organizaVetor(int* escolha, VETOR* v);
void comparaVetores(int* escolhaCompararVal, int* escolha, VETOR* v);

// Cronômetro
void printTempo(int escolha);
void printTempos();
void contagemCronometro(int escolha, unsigned long inicio, unsigned long fim);

// BubbleSort
void bubbleSort(int *vetor, int tamanhoDoVetor);
void troca(int *a, int *b);

// Insertion Sort
void insertionSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);

// Merge Sort
void merge(int vetor[], int comeco, int meio, int fim);
void mergeSort(int vetor[], int comeco, int fim);
```

Se alguém puder dar uma força, ficarei muito agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que antes de perseguir esse *crash* com `malloc()` devia reestruturar o código e deixar do modo mais usual. Assim está frágil e fica difícil até para compilar e achar as coisas.

Ainda sem mexer no código, vou deixar uma opção: um arquivo com os algoritmos, outro com as funções de suporte e outro apenas com `main.c`. Essa é a maneira comum de fazer isso.

- em `main.c` apenas a função. Assim pode escrever facilmente outros programas de teste sem mexer com o código. E nesse arquivo nenhuma declaração ou código fora de `main()`
- em `algo.c` apenas os algoritmos
- em `coisas.c` apenas as funções de suporte ao programa

Talvez concorde que assim fica tudo mais fácil:

```
### algo.h ###

    // algo.h

void bubbleSort(int*, int);
void insertionSort(int[], int);
void merge(int[], int, int, int);
void mergeSort(int[], int, int);
void troca(int*, int*);
```

#### coisas.h

```
#pragma once
#include "algo.h"

float algoritmos[3];

struct vetor
{
    int *vetor[3], tamanhoDoVetor;
};
typedef struct vetor VETOR;

void abertura();
void contagemCronometro(int, unsigned long, unsigned long);
void liberaMem(VETOR*);
void printTempo(int);
void printTempos();

void qualTamanhoDoVetor(int* tamanhoDoVetor);
void geraAleatorio(int tamanhoDoVetor, int vetor[]);
void leDados(int tamanhoDoVetor, int vetor[]);
void printVetor(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void printMerge(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void executaBubbleSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void executaInsertionSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void executaMergeSort(int vetor[], int tamanhoDoVetor);
void inicializaVetor(int* escolha, VETOR* v);
void organizaVetor(int* escolha, VETOR* v);
void comparaVetores(int* escolhaCompararVal, int* escolha, VETOR* v);
```

#### main.c

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "algo.h"
#include "coisas.h"

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int acabou = 0;
    abertura();

    do {
        VETOR v;
        int   escolha, escolhaCompararVal;

        inicializaVetor(&escolha, &v);
        organizaVetor(&escolha, &v);
        comparaVetores(&escolhaCompararVal, &escolha, &v);

        printf(
            "\nVocê deseja usar outro vetor?\n1) Sim\n2) "
            "Não\n\nEscolha: ");
        scanf(" %d", &acabou);
        acabou--;

        liberaMem(&v);

    } while (!acabou);

    if (acabou == 1) { printf("\nTudo bem, até mais! :3\n\n"); }
    else
    {
        printf("\nValor invalido!\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A implementação das funções de `algo.h` está em `algo.c` e de `coisas.h` em `coisas.c`. Assim pode por exemplo escrever programas que usam os algoritmos sem mexer em outros arquivos. Apenas inclui o header.

#### Sobre o programa

Do modo como escreveu tem muita duplicidade. E o menu parece bem supérfluo: está testando apenas 3 algoritmos para fazer exatamente a mesma coisa. Não deveria precisar de 3 segmentos de código praticamente idênticos.
**Mais ainda:** é apenas um sort de um vetor de números que o usuário do programa pode até digitar um por um, então não parece ter sentido ter opções para comparar um método com outro. Os testes vão levar milisegundos se tanto. Apenas classifique o vetor por todos os algoritmos e mostre uma tabela com os resultados.

#### sobre esse trecho

```
    printf("\n\033[1;31mVetor antes da ordenação:\n");
    printVetor(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);

    printf("\n\033[0;32mVetor depois da ordenação:\n");

    switch (*escolha)
    {
        case 1:
            executaBubbleSort(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printVetor(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printTempo(*escolha);
            break;
        case 2:
            executaInsertionSort(v->vetor[1], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printVetor(v->vetor[1], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printTempo(*escolha);
            break;
        case 3:
            executaMergeSort(v->vetor[2], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printMerge(v->vetor[2], v->tamanhoDoVetor);
            printTempo(*escolha);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Não é tudo a mesma coisa? Só muda o algoritmo então devia ser um código só...

```
    printf("\n\033[1;31mVetor antes da ordenação:\n");
    printVetor(v->vetor[0], v->tamanhoDoVetor);

    printf("\n\033[0;32mVetor depois da ordenação:\n");
```

Não use códigos desse tipo embutidos no meio de `printf()`. A cada vez que mudar de idéia sobre alguma cor vai perder um tempo enorme procurando isso. Use encapsulamento e escreva uma função que escreva com a cor configurada.

```
void organizaVetor(int* escolha, VETOR* v)
{
    printf(
        "\nQual algorítmo de ordenação você deseja usar?\n1) Bubble "
        "Sort\n2) Insertion Sort\n3) Merge Sort\n\nDigite: ");
    scanf("%d", escolha);
```

Teste **SEMPRE** o retorno de `scanf()`. É ingênuo seguir adiante.

E porque passa um ponteiro com uma opção do menu? Isso é uma entrada e não vai mudar nunca.

E porque um menu em um programa que nem está pronto ainda? Nunca escreva um programa interativo. Só vai perder tempo.

[image: 3 sort]

Entenda que em toda parte aparecem esses argumentos, o vetor e o tamanho. Isso sugere que eles devia estar juntos em uma estrutura...

#### o vetor de teste

Como deve usar sempre o mesmo vetor não parece haver razão para incluir `time.h` apenas para mudar a semente do gerador. É melhor usar uma constante conhecida. E ao chamar os algoritmos chamar a partir de uma única função que retorna uma cópia do vetor original. É muito mais simples.